# Can you change a text input to textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change a text field to a textarea while entering data and then have it revert back to a text field once the user tabs of clicks outside of the textarea?

Comment: ___[`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)___

Comment: yes it is but i found it very unusual thing to do...why don't you use textarea initially with small height which looks as a text field and then increase its height on click which looks like a textarea..this will be more feasable..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution would be to do it in the css.
Something like this:

CSS:

```
.testInput:focus
{
  height: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="text" class="testInput"> </textarea>
```

See working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Lk1a5wyh/

Comment: What is the point of increasing the height if user can not write in the next line ?

Comment: you'r welcome, could you mark it as the answer, it would mean a lot to me :)

Comment: will once the time passes

Comment: i like your answer, but would prefer setting a css class on the object in questing rather than setting the height directly

Answer (score 2):

What you should ask yourself is "Why?".

You should manipulate size, look and feel through CSS and not with types of elements.

For usability, accessibility and plain understanding what is going on you really should avoid doing stuff like that.

Edit:
Just add css classes something like this:

```
input {
    height:50px; 
}

input:focus {
    height:200px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use hidden textarea for this functionality:

HTML Code:

```
<textarea id="text" style="display:none"> </textarea>
<input id="input1"></input>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input1').focus(function() {
    $('#text').show();
    $("#input1").hide();
    $("#text").focus();
  });
  $('#text').blur(function() {
    var val1 = $(this).val();
    $("#input1").val(val1);
    $(this).hide();
    $("#input1").show();
  })
});
```

[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/s1L03nep/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('input[size="100"]').each(function () {
var style = $(this).attr('style'),
    textbox = $(document.createElement('textarea')).attr('style', style);
$(this).replaceWith(textbox);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this using vanilla JS. ( input to textarea copying all input attributes )

```
let input_el = document.querySelector('input[id="inputName"]');
let textarea_el = document.createElement('textarea');
input_el.getAttributeNames().forEach( attrName => {
    textarea_el.setAttribute( attrName, 
      (document.createAttribute( attrName ).value =            
       input_el.getAttribute( attrName ) )
    );
});
textarea_el.setAttribute('rows', '1');
input_el.replaceWith(textarea_el);
```